# Javacard 3.1 to 3.04 converter

Tags: javacard

Does anyone have any experience with Javacard tools 3.1?

I've run through the "installation and getting started": https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javacard/3.1/guide/introduction.html

I can build / run / simulate and debug the demos in eclipse. Generating CAP files for 3.1 and 3.0.5

But when I run the converter to target 3.0.4 files, there is a verification error:

```
[ INFO: ] Converting CAP file HelloWorld with target version 3.0.4

[ INFO: ] Converter [v3.1.0]
[ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
    
    
parsing C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Java Card Development Kit Simulator 3.1.0\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\bin\com\oracle\jcclassic\samples\helloworld\HelloWorld.class
converting com.oracle.jcclassic.samples.helloworld.HelloWorld
writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Java Card Development Kit Simulator 3.1.0\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\deliverables\HelloWorld\com\oracle\jcclassic\samples\helloworld\javacard\helloworld.exp
writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Java Card Development Kit Simulator 3.1.0\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\deliverables\HelloWorld\com\oracle\jcclassic\samples\helloworld\javacard\helloworld.jca
Verifier Error: Version number mismatch on imported package javacard/framework (AID a0:0:0:0:62:1:1):
imported version is 1.6, export file version is 1.5

Verification failed
[ INFO: ] conversion completed with 1 errors and 0 warnings.
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\java" "-Djc.home=C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\.." -classpath "C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\api_classic_annotations-3.1.0.jar;C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\api_classic-3.1.0.jar;C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\tools.jar;C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\json.jar;C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\jctasks_tools.jar;C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\commons-logging-1.2-9f99a00.jar;C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\commons-cli-1.4.jar;C:\java\java_card_tools-win-bin-b_108-06_jan_2021\bin\\..\lib\asm-8.0.1.jar;" com.sun.javacard.converter.Main -config "C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Java Card Development Kit Simulator 3.1.0\samples\classic_applets\HelloWorld\applet\configurations\HelloWorld.conf"
```

Has anyone seen this, or any idea what it could be? I only have the basic install from "Guide" link.